# FILEPROPERTY - SPACEUSED

Tags: sql-server, filegroups

I used `SELECT FILEPROPERTY('file_name', 'SpaceUsed')`, and it returns NULL, what does it mean?

I am correctly using it in the correct database.

I cannot assume that `NULL` means empty since:

I tried to create a new database (test2), then query `SELECT FILEPROPERTY('test2', 'SpaceUsed')`. It already has a value.

Comment: According to the documentation, you need to specify a filename not a filegroup name: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/fileproperty-transact-sql

Comment: @SeanGallardy-Microsoft, done testing. I will revise my question. What does it mean when some of the filename returns NULL in FILEPROPERTY..spaceused? Some are not.

Comment: Hi @SeanGallardy-Microsoft, I revised my question. I am now using file name. But I wonder why on the production, there are some that returns NULL. Tried in my local environment, even a newly created database returns a value.

Comment: null is returned when the database file provided does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FILEPROPERTY is expecting a file (not a filegroup).
Make sure the the name you pass in parameter is on one of those :

select name from sys.database_files

This query will give you information about the data files of the selected database:

```
With A as 
(SELECT db_name() as [Database],fg.name as [FilegroupName],  RTRIM(f.name) AS [Segment Name], f.groupid AS [Group Id], f.filename AS [File Name], 
CAST(f.size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Size in MB],CAST(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Space Used],
CAST(size/128.0-(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Available Space],
CAST((CAST(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(f.size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)))*100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Percent Used] 
FROM sysfiles f join sys.filegroups fg on f.groupid=fg.data_space_id ) 
select 1 as [order], * from A union  select 2 as [order], REPLICATE('-',10), REPLICATE('-',10), REPLICATE('-',10), 0, REPLICATE('-',50),0,0,0,0 
union 
select 3 as [order], [Database],[FilegroupName],  '', [Group Id], '', sum([Size in MB]), sum([Space Used]), sum([Available Space]), Cast(sum([Space Used])/sum([Size in MB])*100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
from A 
group by [Database],[FilegroupName], [Group Id] 
ORDER BY [order], [Segment Name]
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I revised my question. I am now using file name. But I wonder why on the production, there are some that returns NULL. Tried in my local environment, even a newly created database returns a value.

Comment: pretty hard to tell without any information regarding those prod instances :(

Comment: run the "select name from sys.database_files" on the databases that returns null... The database file may not be the same as the database name.

Comment: thanks for the tip. Because of your query I found the cause. I forgot to mention that I am using name in sys.master_files for the parameter in FILEPROPERTY. That name was different on what was returned in sysfiles.  When in SSMS, it's the "Logical Name" that should be used instead.

Comment: @DominiqueBoucher is there a way to run this query from the master db context and return results for all databases?

Comment: I think you could use this :select DB_NAME(database_id) "db", name "FileName", case when type_desc ='Rows' then 'Data File' when type_desc ='Log' then 'Log File' end "FileType" from sys.master_files to returns all the file name. If you want to run the select fileproperty on each, then it will required dynamic query. Is that what you want ?

Comment: Here's a script that will returned the used space for all file of all DBs:  exec sp_MSforeachdb ' use [?];
select ''?'' "db", name, type_desc, size*0.0078125 as "Size (Mb)", FILEPROPERTY(name, ''spaceused'')*0.0078125 as "Used Space (Mb)", cast(cast(FILEPROPERTY(name, ''spaceused'') as float)*100/cast (size as float) as decimal (10,2)) as "used percent" 
from sys.database_files '